# Why method updateSearchResultsForSearchController is not called?

Tags: swift, uisearchcontroller

I have a UICollectionViewController that maintains a recipes collection.

```
class RecipesViewController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UICollectionViewDataSource  {
```

And another UICollectionViewController for maintaining results of the search, also implementing the UISearchResultsUpdating like that:

```
class SearchResultsController: UICollectionViewController, UISearchResultsUpdating,UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UICollectionViewDataSource { ...
```

I need to search into the collection, so I have a member into RecipesViewController

```
var searchController: UISearchController!
```

also initiated like that:

```
let resultsController = SearchResultsController()
resultsController.recipes = recipes
resultsController.filteredResults = recipes

searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: resultsController)
searchController.searchResultsUpdater = resultsController
```

I placed into the header of RecipesViewController the UISearchBar from searchController.

My problem is that SearchResultsController is not updating when text is entered into searchBar. Method updateSearchResultsForSearchController is not even called.

Answer (score 2):

```
@interface YourViewController_CollectionResults () <UISearchResultsUpdating>

@end

@implementation YourViewController_CollectionResults
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    // The collection view controller is in a nav controller, and so the containing nav controller is the 'search results controller'
    UINavigationController *searchResultsController = [[self storyboard] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"CollectionSearchResultsNavController"];

    self.searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:searchResultsController];

    //It's really import that you class implement <UISearchResultsUpdating> 
    self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;

    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchController.searchBar;

    self.definesPresentationContext = YES;

}
```

You have an example in this github

[Sample-UISearchController](https://github.com/dempseyatgithub/Sample-UISearchController)

I hope that this example solves your problem.

Comment: That's much better.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a lazy instantiation for the search controller:

```
    self.searchController = ({
        // Setup One: This setup present the results in the current view.
        let controller = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
        controller.searchResultsUpdater = self
        controller.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
        controller.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        controller.searchBar.searchBarStyle = .Minimal
        controller.searchBar.sizeToFit()
        self.tableView.tableHeaderView = controller.searchBar
        return controller
    })()
```

I hope that help!

Comment: Thank you, but I need a sample using the search controller within a UICollectionViewController. I have 2 collections, first is for whole collection and the other is for managing the results, also conforms to the UISearchResultsUpdating. It seems I missed something when splitting the search between both collections.

Comment: I tried using also your first suggestion, with UISearchControllerDelegate with no success.

Comment: Try change self.tableview to self.collectionview (not sure if exist but worst a try)

Comment: I've put the search bar as a header in the RecipesViewController, using UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader.